# MySQL - UNION ALL query - Unknown column error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which produces an error #1054

> Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'unit_name' in 'field list'"

```
    SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('theme:', theme_pk) AS global_id,
       theme_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM theme 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name) AS global_id,
       strand_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM strand
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name) AS global_id,
       strandyear_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM strandyear sy 
INNER JOIN strand s ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk

UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM unit u 
INNER JOIN strandyear sy ON u.strandyear_fk = sy.strandyear_pk
INNER JOIN strand s ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk

UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS global_id,
       rotation_discipline_block_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM unit u 
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN strandyear sy ON u.strandyear_fk = sy.strandyear_pk
INNER JOIN strand s ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk

UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block r ON u.unit_pk = r.unit_fk
INNER JOIN strandyear sy ON u.strandyear_fk = sy.strandyear_pk
INNER JOIN strand s ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCjfHH2ZfrP3Ft25U3hnKt/0)

The problem is in the last `INNER JOINS` of the query.  You can see in this [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cKVk3rViFZnNr87bYBGytC/1) that omitting the last `UNION ALL` and `SELECT` works fine.  The solution is probably simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: your last query does not join to `unit` table so you don't have access to `unit_name` column

Comment: yes, you call `u.unit_pk = r.unit_fk` and `u.strandyear_fk = sy.strandyear_pk `without unit table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In last query while `union` table 'rotation_discipline_block' appeared twice.
Last query should be like this.

```
SELECT CONCAT('theme:',
              theme_fk,
              ',strand:',
              strand_name,
              ',strandyear:',
              strandyear_name,
              ',unit:',
              unit_name,
              ',rotation_discipline_block:',
              rotation_discipline_block_name,
              ',learning_event:',
              learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:',
              theme_fk,
              ',strand:',
              strand_name,
              ',strandyear:',
              strandyear_name,
              ',unit:',
              unit_name,
              ',rotation_discipline_block:',
              rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
    FROM learning_event le
 INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb
    ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk
 INNER JOIN Unit
    ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
 INNER JOIN strandyear sy
    ON u.strandyear_fk = sy.strandyear_pk
 INNER JOIN strand s
    ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed the last part of the query to:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN strandyear sy ON u.strandyear_fk = sy.strandyear_pk
INNER JOIN strand s ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk
```